compile successfully string subscript out of range
guys,i am encountering a problem i`ve never ever seen! i am writing a problem that reverse the order of chars in a string without changing order of block of char,something like this,I am a student to student a am I and the following is my code,it can be compiled successfully,but when i input the eg,it seemed that debug assertion failed
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int x = 0;
string reverse(string am);
int main() {
    string st1;
    getline(cin,st1);
    reverse(st1);
    cout << st1.length();
    cout<<st1;
    return 0;
}

string reverse(string am) {
    string st2;
    int i, k, j, r;
    for (i = 0; i < am.length(); i++) {
        
        if (am[i] == ' ') {
            x = i;
            for (k = am.length() - 1; k >= am.length() - i; k--) {
                st2[k] = am[x-1];
                x--;
            }
            if (i != -1) {
                st2[i] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    for (r = x + 1,j=0; r< am.length(); i++,j++) {
        st2[j] = am[r];
    }
    return st2;
}

what could i do to solve the problem
here is the exact warning
enter image description here

st2 is empty when you try to assign to st2[k].  You should track where the last space was, and use substr to copy that whole section.

Accessing elements of an empty string is undefined behavior. See similar problem. Segmentation fault while accessing vector elements

Also, after fixing the out-of-range access, you might find that the call to reverse(st1); takes a copy of st1 and reverses the copy. It doesn't affect the original!

FYI: what could i do to solve the problem -- If you used a stack, plus not have to check for spaces by simply using std::istringstream, this is trivial.  The stack is a data structure that is last-in, first out, which is exactly how the final output is produced.

Here is how I would approach this.
Note you should really take care NOT to copy strings if you don't have to. E.g. use std::string reverse(const std::string& string).
Also avoid using index based for loops if you can, they have a tendency to result in out of bound access as you already notices.
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

// using namespace std; <== NO do NOT use this, it is not recommended

// Make a function that creates views on substrings
// and return a std::vector of those views (so NO strings are copied)
auto split_string(std::string_view string, std::string_view delimiters)
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> substrings;

    if ((string.size() == 0ul))
    {
        return substrings;
    }
    
    if (delimiters.size() == 0ul)
    {
        substrings.emplace_back(string);
        return substrings;
    }

    auto start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters);
    auto end_pos = start_pos;
    auto max_length = string.length();

    while (start_pos < max_length)
    {
        end_pos = std::min(max_length, string.find_first_of(delimiters, start_pos));

        if (end_pos != start_pos)
        {
            substrings.emplace_back(&string[start_pos], end_pos - start_pos);
            start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters, end_pos);
        }
    }

    return substrings;
}


int main()
{
    std::string_view test{ "I am a student" };

    // split the string on any of those tokens
    auto strings = split_string(test, " "); // tokens can also be ".!"
           
    // In C++20 use reverse view
    for (const auto string : strings | std::views::reverse )
    {
        std::cout << string << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Pre C++20 you can use rbegin/rend to iterate backward
    for(auto it = strings.rbegin(); it != strings.rend(); ++it )
    {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
}

